# strange error with SVN LS command, when using another revision number

Tags: svn

What does it mean:

```
$ svn ls -r 2195 ^/trunk
library/
$ svn ls -r 2195 ^/trunk/library
svn: File not found: revision 2263, path '/trunk/library'
```

What could be the reason of this strange behavior? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
$ svn ls -r 2195 ^/trunk
library/
$ svn ls ^/trunk/library@r2195
abc/
```

I don't know why, but now it works...